# For which values of $a\in\mathbb{C}$ does $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{a^n}{n}$ converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, power-series

> For which complex values of $a$ does $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{a^n}{n}$ converge?

Clearly when $|a|>1$ it does not and when $|a|<1$ it does, so we only have to see what happens when $|a|=1$.

I am rather stumped with this problem. I have shown if $a$ has an even order then the sum converges. It is also clear if $a=1$ then it diverges.

I think this is the only value for which it diverges, but I am not sure, any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is the *order* of a number?

Comment: the smallest positive integer $k$ so that $a^k=1$. Not all unitary complex numbers have an order, but I have shown it to be true for those that do have order, and whose order is even.

Comment: @Bernard I'm sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: Don't be sorry. This point had to be clarified, as speaking of the  order of a number implies this number be an algebraic number – and a rather special kind of algebraic number, from the point of view of Galois theory.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By [Dirichlet's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet's_test), the series converges for $|a|=1$ unless $a=1$, since the partial sums of $\sum_na^n$ are bounded.

Comment: I'm having a hard time seeing why the partial sums are bounded

Comment: @CarryonSmiling: Do you know the formula for the partial sums of a geometric series?

Comment: Oh yeah, duh, that was so silly of me. Thank you very much.